# WordPress ajax-action how to return content

Tags: ajax, actions

So I'm trying to set up an AJAX action for a plugin I'm building.

When using `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=beacon_podio-get_apps`

I was just getting `hello world0` and I'm not seeing `Request is valid` or the `Invalid request` so it seems like the action is not being called

I think I'm missing something but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
class testClass {

    public function __construct(){
        echo "hello world";
        add_action('wp_ajax_beacon_podio-get_apps', array($this, "get_apps"));
    }

    public function get_apps(){
        if(isset($_POST['app_id'])){
            $app_id = $_POST['app_id'];
            die("Request is valid");
        }else{
            die("Invalid request");
        }
    }
}
new testClass();
```

I have been reading https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins but it's missing the URL I'm supposed to be using.

[image: Output from wordpress]

Comment: @Krzysiek Dróżdż why did you remove the plugin-developer tag this is clearly a plugin development issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be a bug in WordPress, coming back to this and upgrading to version 5.2 the problem seems to have been fixed for some reason the has_action was failing to find the action unsure why but it seems to have been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so you misunderstood it a little bit, I guess...

You do the first part correctly. So yes - AJAX requests should be sent to `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and the should have `action` param set in the request (either as a POST or as a GET).

But then, you do it wrong. You register your action with this code:

```
add_action('beacon_podio-get_apps', array($this, "get_apps"));
```

But id should be:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_beacon_podio-get_apps', array($this, "get_apps"));
```

or (for anonymous users)

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_beacon_podio-get_apps', array($this, "get_apps"));
```

So just to make it clear - the correct hooks are:

- `wp_ajax_(action)`
- `wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)`

where (action) is the action that you sent as action parameter.

Comment: Also, IIRC, the `wp_ajax_nopriv_*` actions *don't run* if the user is signed in, so if you want it to run whether the user is logged in or not, you need to hook to both.

Comment: ok so i have changed it to `add_action('wp_ajax_beacon_podio-get_apps', array($this, "get_apps"));` and i'm getting the same thing im still not seeing the output with trying `?action=beacon_podio-get_app` and `?action=wp_ajax_beacon_podio-get_app`

Comment: I have updated question to show the new code and that I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the URL, but it does mean one of the URL's I was using was correct I am logged in and want it to be for logged in only users. so I'm using the correct one. but it still is not working

Comment: No, it only means that you're ignoring a large part of answer (and original article from Codex)... And sorry, I can't help with that. I've already mentioned it twice.

Comment: Yeah, just coz the codex says it does not mean it's correct, Look at my updated code if I have missed part of your answer in that new code what have I missed, I have the action as you said, i'm using the correct one for logged in users according to your answer but it still is not working.